# jQuery txt file content show / hide

Tags: jquery, text-files, show-hide

I have a script that loads information from a text file and reload the file every x seconds so every time when the text file will be updated that will be visible.

But is it possible to show the div x seconds and then it will be hidden. And when the text file change content it will popup again for a few seconds and then it will hide again and so on?

**What i have now**:

```
function readTxtfile() {
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "textfile.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
        var lines = data.split(','),
            htmlLines = '<p>' + lines.join('</p><p>') + '</p>';

        jQuery("#info_container .txt").html(htmlLines);
        setTimeout(readTxtfile, 5000);
        }
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    readTxtfile();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use setInterval instead of setTimeout since you are running your request every X ms. That's something you could do:

```js
var TIME_TO_SHOW = 2000;
var TIME_FOR_REQUEST = 1000;
var currentContent = null;
var hideTimeout = null;
    
function readTxtfile() {
  var data = $("#inputtxt").val();
  
  if(currentContent === data) {
    //if content read is the same as actual content, do nothing
    return; 
  }
  currentContent = data;

  var lines = data.split(',');
  htmlLines = '<p>' + lines.join('</p><p>') + '</p>';

  $("#info_container .txt").html(htmlLines);
  $("#info_container .txt").show(); //show div on text edited
  if(hideTimeout) {
    //this will prevent the div to get hidden by a timeout which
    //has been started before
    clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
  }
  hideTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#info_container .txt").hide();
    hideTimeout = null;
  }, TIME_TO_SHOW);//Hide the the div after 2 seconds
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //check for modifications every second
  var interval = setInterval(readTxtfile, TIME_FOR_REQUEST);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="inputtxt" type="text" name="test" value="Edit me"></input>

<div id="info_container">
  <div class="txt" style="display: none;">Test</div>
</div>
```

If for some reason you have to stop requesting the file you could use in this case: `clearInterval(interval)`

**EDIT**
I've added a code snippet in which i use an input text, you could use the same approach with your ajax request

Comment: Hi, when you load the page then the content of the txt will hide, thats good. But when i change the content of the txt file it will not popup again? (only on reload of the page)

Comment: This is working great, thnx! Maybe is this little feature possible? When you saves the textfile and you have like 3 saves on almost the same time and the time_for_request is 7 sec and the_time_show is 6 second then he only shows the third save of the textfile and not the first and the second save. Is it possible that jQuery saves it or something? And shows first the First save then the second and then the third?

Comment: With a delay of 7 seconds between the requests it's not possible because jquery will read the file only after 7 seconds, if the file changes during this period it's not possible to show changes made in these seconds.
The simplest thing you can do is to set a lower delay for the request for example: 1 second.

Comment: But when i put it on 1 second then i have no pauze between them. It must be like an alert. Example: textfile change - text show for 5 seconds and hide. Then the second will popup and so on. (so the one change will not interfere with the other but will wait when the animation is done.)

Comment: It's possible, this could be a little tricky because you have to handle a queue of edits done and show them for a specified time in order.
As possible as i can i'll add a new code snipped with this feature, meanwhile you should set a lower delay for the request, and then think for a way to handle a this feature: i'd create an array in which I'll add all edits got from the requests and then i'd tail it with another `setInterval`, so you can show up the first revision of the content for 5 seconds and after that the second revision will show up and then after 5 seconds the third and so on...

Comment: That the delay is 1 second is fine if jQuery can temporary save all the edits and do the animations then. :-). I dont see a updated code?

Answer (score 0):

There's always the direct approach with `.show()` and `.hide()`

```
function readTxtfile() {
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "textfile.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
        var lines = data.split(','),
            htmlLines = '<p>' + lines.join('</p><p>') + '</p>';

        var element = jQuery("#info_container .txt")
        if ( htmlLines == element.html()) {
            element.hide();
        } else {
            element.html(htmlLines).show();
        }
        setTimeout(readTxtfile, 5000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Joe, this is not working? When i change the txt file the content wont popup and hide again after x seconds?